# returning a string from plotly's write_html

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-express

I'm trying to have plotly express return a string of a div object in html so I can integrate it with other packages. I am trying to follow the documentation (Plotly v5.17.0), and I feel like I'm doing what it tells me to do, but no success.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious (apologies if so) but within the documents in Python I am seeing:

> full_html: bool (default True)
> If True, produce a string containing a complete HTML document
> starting with an <html> tag.  If False, produce a string containing
> a single <div> element.

and:

> Returns
> -------
> str
> Representation of figure as an HTML div string

Yet, while I can write this div element to a file no problem by making this call with `div = fig.write_html(filename, full_html=False)` it will return `None` every time.

Comment: maybe it need to run without `filename` to get it as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found issue in Plotly GitHub: [plotly.io.write_html return · Issue #3599 · plotly/plotly.py](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3599)

It seems there is mistake in documentation. You have to use [.to_html()](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.io.to_html.html).

```
div = fig.to_html(full_html=False)
```

---

**BTW:**

It generates string with `~ 3 600 000 chars`(`~ 3.5MB`) because it includes all `JavaScript` code.

Using `include_plotlyjs=False` you get only `~ 8 000 chars`

```
div = fig.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs=False)
```

Comment: thank you! In my case I do want the js code, but it's a good note so as to make sure you only do it once if you're creating multiple divs